# RegEx matching for Neo4j numeric property

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I have a couple of nodes sharing a property with a numeric value. I would like to filter on this property using a reular expression. Is this possible using the Cypher Query Language?

Example:

```
A { num: 3 }
B { num: 12 }
C { num: 532 }
D { num: 1423 }
```

How can I get all nodes where the `num` property contains the digit `3` (should return A, C and D). I've tried something like `n.num =~ '3'`, but it results in an error ("`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String)`")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this, you are trying to apply a RegExp to a property of type Long, which is not valid. Defining the node properties as strings will work, see http://tinyurl.com/bqoq62q

Otherwise, there is support for autocasting coming up, so you could (in future versions of Cypher) do `where (node.num+'') =~ '3'` to do this even with a Long. But not now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on the cypher stuff (that doesn't look like regex at all), but the regular expression you'd want is something like this (assuming that you cannot have nested curly braces; if you can, regex is impossible for this).

```
([A-Z]\s*\{[^\}]*num:\s*3\D[^\}]*\})
```

That will match a single capital letter, followed by an open curly brace, and has num: 3 before any closing curly brace. The entire thing is remembered for later thanks to the parentheses.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear in my question. The problem is more of a typecast one (how can I convert the numeric value 3 into a string "3", so that I can apply the regEx) and not how to get the right regular expression. The example above shows some Neo4j nodes, not the string I want to match...

Comment: Aaaand - it's working thanks to the contribution of @wfreeman, see https://github.com/neo4j/community/pull/885 in Neo4j 1.9-SNAPSHOT.